# How to add -shell-escape option to latex compile command

Tags: latex, compile

Background story:

I have to compile my LaTeX document with the `-shell-escape` command line option because the pgfplots library I am using calls `gnuplot`. This was necessary to get a plot of a recursive function requiring double precision fpu.

Problem:

When I hit `C-c C-C` or `C-c C-f` in emacs (GNU Emacs 26.3) the document is compiled using `pdflatex \\nonstopmode\\input mydoc.tex` but the plot in the PDF output document stays empty, because of some restrictions. When I compile manually using `pdflatex -shell-escape \\nonstopmode\\input mydoc.tex` everything works just fine.

Failed attempts:

I have set `tex-start-options` variable in the 'tex run group' to `"-shell-escape"`, but it did not appear in the tex-shell.

Update:

Meanwhile I have installed AUCTeX as suggested.
I am still curious to find out how the issue can be solved without it.

Comment: See my answer for possible gotcha's in setting `tex-start-options`, but that *should* work.

Comment: By any chance have you set `latex-run-command`? I think I've found a bug.

Answer (score 2):

For the built-in TeX mode (i.e. not AucTeX), you can customize the variable `tex-start-options`: do `C-h v tex-start-options` and hit the `Customize` link. Enter `--shell-escape` as the value string, hit `Apply` or `Apply and Save` and try `C-c C-c` in your TeX file again.

EDIT: I see you said you tried this. I did too and it works fine. Maybe you didn't apply the customization? BTW, you can only tell by looking at the command at the top of the resulting `*tex-shell*` buffer: the prompt still says `pdflatex` (or whatever).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-shell-escape`?

Comment: The AucTeX equivalent is `TeX-command-extra-options`.

Comment: @young_souvlaki: both versions work AFAIK with every processor (`pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`). The usual convention is a double dash for long options and a single dash for short options, so I try to encourage the universal adoption of that convention :-)

Comment: Yea I like that thinking, `-shell-escape` does look odd.

Comment: I haven't had any luck with tex-start-options in latex-mode. It seems to ignore the setting.

Answer (score 0):

### My favourite solution :

I have composed this small function in my init file that I find convenient.

```el
      (defun TeX-command-toggle-shell-escape ()
    "toggles the option --shell-escape from the tex command"
            (interactive)
            (setq TeX-command-extra-options
                  (cond ((string-match-p "\\_<--shell-escape\\_>" TeX-command-extra-options )
                         (replace-regexp-in-string "\\_<--shell-escape\\_>" "" TeX-command-extra-options))
                        ((string-empty-p TeX-command-extra-options)"--shell-escape")
                        (t(format "--shell-escape %s" TeX-command-extra-options))))
            (message "TeX-command-extra-options : `%s'" TeX-command-extra-options))
```

You can bind it to "C-c C-t C-x" (for instance).'
Using the package `bind-key` syntax :

```el
    (bind-key "C-c C-t C-X" #'TeX-command-toggle-shell-escape  LaTeX-mode-map)
```

So, the key sequence "C-c C-t C-x" activates or deactivates the shell-escape option.

### Other solution :

You can add a local variable to your source file

```el
    % Local Variables:
    % TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
    % End:
```

But the file has to be reloaded to activate the variable - or you can do `M-x normal-mode` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply. I've copied your local variable solution to the end of my document adding ```% mode: tex```. When I reloaded it, there was a warning about possibly dangerous options and I had to confirm, what I did. But still ```-shell-escape``` is not added to to the command appearing in the tex-shell buffer. I can't find ```TeX-command-extra-options``` in the variable documentation. Could it be that it does not exist an my system?

Comment: Mode should be LaTeX, it is default using AUCTeX. Are you using AUCTeX ?

Comment: No, sorry I am not using AUCTeX - just ordinary tex-mode and company.

Comment: Thats not incompatible. AUCTeX is for Emacs, pdftex is for TeXLive. To install AUCTeX on Emacs : M-x package-install RET auctex RET. Or check C-h v AUCTeX-version if installed

Comment: I got aware of the misunderstanding as soon I hit the add-comment button. I've edited the original comment.

Comment: Sorry, I cant help, I do not use ordinary tex-mode.

Comment: I've installed AUCTeX. Compilation works just fine now. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: If this solution works for you, you could check it. It might help others.

Answer (score 0):

|I use this minor mode:

```
(define-minor-mode tex-command-shell-escape-mode
    "Enable compilation with -shell-escape"
    :init 1
    :lighter " -shell-escape"
    (setq  TeX-command-extra-options
           (if (string-empty-p  TeX-command-extra-options)
               "-shell-escape"
             "")))
```

You can bind it to `C-c C-t C-x` for instance to toggle the shell-escape mode.

```
(bind-key "C-c C-t C-X" #'tex-command-shell-escape-mode LaTeX-mode-map)
```

This probably shouldn't work properly if you're using `TeX-command-extra-option` for some other purpose elsewhere. It's not my case.